# Parse tor exit-address list

Tags: python, tor

Would like to parse IPv4 address from [exit-addresses](http://exitlist.torproject.org/exit-addresses). Format of the file:

```
ExitNode 006C3FA7C3F6E3ACD13D0DD9B10C7DFA933C237B
Published 2012-06-12 05:04:03
LastStatus 2012-06-12 06:03:22
ExitAddress 220.0.231.71 2012-06-12 10:23:05
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('data.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        if line.startswith('ExitAddress'):
            print line.split()[1]
```

will give you

```
220.0.231.71
```

where `data.txt` contains the four lines you posted (I also ran it with the big file you linked to). Using `with` will also "automagically" close your file for you when you are done, or an exception is encountered.

This [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will collect all of the data in a list for you once the data file has been opened:

```
   a = [line.split()[1] for line in inf if line.startswith('ExitAddress')]
```

or alternatively, if you don't want to collect the whole list in memory at once, you could use a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
   g = (line.split()[1] for line in inf if line.startswith('ExitAddress'))
```

You'll also have take care of closing the file yourself.

Comment: There is no need to split() every line, you can split only if the conditional is true.